# Get an overlapped subset from a data in Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

I have a data matrix `TxM`. My model needs to grab a subset of size `txM` for each point along `T`. That is I have a total of `(T-t)*(txM)` data to process. Each of this selection can actually be processed independently, where the result must be collect to a storage. Below is my current implement which I believe is not the best.

```
# D is a tensor os shape TxM
idx = tf.placeholder(shape=(), tf.int32)
slice = tf.slice(D, [idx, 0], [t, M])
for t in range(T-t):
  res = sess.run([my_op], feed_dict={idx: t})  
  collection.append(res)
```

I believe there must be a better way to run the `my_op` in parallel. Each operation is independent and can be placed in GPU. Any idea to speed up the procedure?

Comment: You can construct graph and feed_dict in a loop and call `collection=sess.run(my_op_list, idx_dict)` outside of the loop

Answer (score 0):

You can use `tf.extract_image_patches` to obtain an overlapped subset:

```
tf.squeeze(tf.extract_image_patches(X[tf.newaxis,:,:,tf.newaxis], ksizes=(1,t,1,1), strides=(1,1,1,1), rates=(1,1,1,1), padding='VALID'))
```